# PHP how to get server host from PHP.ini

Tags: php

How do I read the server host fromPHP.init?

I want to copy a site from my `localhost` to a production sever and have it work without having to change any code. I figurd that this would be the best way to do it

Comment: php.ini has no idea about your server host. For getting other php.ini vars is `ini_get` function.

Comment: In most situations where you create absolute URLs server-site that point to the site itself, you would make use of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ini file from the production server in your development environment to avoid any surprises when you move your code from dev to production. If you need to do something differently in your code see if

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

is set and, if it is, extract the domain and do whatever you need to based on the value of the domain.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {

    $hostbu = explode('.',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $domain = $hostbu[(count($hostbu) - 2)] . '.' . $hostbu[(count($hostbu) - 1)];

} else {$domain = '';}  // end of if the server variable HTTP_HOST is set; else set domain to null

// we are NOT on the development machine
// change the logic to see if you are on the production machine depending on your needs

if ($domain != 'devdomain.com') {  

    spl_autoload_extensions(".class"); // may be a comma-separated list of extensions
    spl_autoload_register();
// do anything else you need to do here

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave. What is that spl stuff doing? Just curios

Comment: Best source is the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ref.spl.php Makes it trivial to autoload classes and, with the proper include path in php.ini, allows you to keep everything outside of the web root.

Comment: ICIC. Thanks. Btw, what does `hostbu` mean?  and why`$domain`? For me, `$hostbu` = `localhost` and `$domain` = `.localhost`, with leading dot. What are you doing there? Just so I can understand.

Comment: hostbu is simply a variable name. It may be anything you'd like. The logic determines the domain the code is being run on and can do different things depending on what the domain is. In my example, copied from production code, if the code is NOT being run on the development machine then the 2 calls to the spl functions are made. In the production environment those calls have already been done for me. Just change the logic test to match your environment. I used a full domain name on my local development machine instead of localhost FWIW.

Comment: Thanks, Dave, I learned soemthing today. I guess that I will stick with menaingful variable names :-)